# Convert multiple if-else statement into switch-case for objects

Tags: javascript, if-statement, switch-statement

I have an object in which I have to verify different values using multiple if-else statements, like below is sample javascript snippet:

```
if(properties.values.a > 0 ){

}else if(properties.values.b > 0){

}else if(properties.values.c > 0){

}else if(properties.values.d > 0){

}else if(properties.values.e > 0){

}else{

}
```

I am willing to replace this multiple if-else statement into switch-case. Now I wonder if that is possible for objects or not? If possible, how should be going towards it?

Comment: what should happen inside of the then parts?

Comment: @NinaScholz assume it to have any xyz code to get executed

Comment: does it have always the same call?

Comment: This is better as an `if/else` statement because each test is on a different expression. `switch` is more suited for checking one expression for many possible values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch is not supposed to work like this. So, no, this is not supported.
As a workaround you could do this

```
switch (true) {
    case (properties.values.a > 0):
        ...
    case (properties.values.b > 0):
        ...
    case (properties.values.c > 0):
        ...
    case (properties.values.d > 0):
        ...
    case (properties.values.e > 0):
        ...
}
```

Still, is pretty ugly so i suggest you stick to if/else.

Comment: In the strictest sense, you are using `switch` exactly as it was intended (meaning you are using a perfectly legal configuration) to work and so, it is fully supported, just not advised.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with a `for in` loop:

```js
o = {
  a:0,
  b:0,
  c:1,
  d:0
};

for(var p in o) {
    if (o[p] > 0) {
      //...
      console.log(o[p]);
      break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe yours would be an answer when I have similar expression to be executed on every iteration

Answer (score 1):

You could use an array with the wanted keys and use iterate with a short circuit if a value is found.

If no one is found call `callOther`.

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'].some(k => {
    if (properties.values[k] > 0) {
        callThis();
        return true;
    }
}) || callOther();
```

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript you can only use `switch` to check for equality. You can't check whether `a > b` using a switch.

If you want a more elegant solution, that I particularly would only use if I needed to check a huge amount of rules, is to do something like this:

```
const checkers = [];
checkers.push([p => p.values.a > 0, () => { /* do something */ }])
checkers.push([p => p.values.b > 0, () => { /* do something */ }])
...
checkers.filter(checker => checker[0](property)).forEach(checker => checker[1]())
```

In the above example, checkers is an array of arrays in which the first element is a predicate function and the second is a function that should execute if the predicate is true.

But again... For most cases you just do an `if/else` as you described.

Also, if you want to check if a value is greater than 0, you might use just `if(a)`, because if `a` is not `0`, then it's truthy, otherwise it's falsy.

**EDIT**

Apparently, technically, you can use logical expressions within `switch` statements, even though it seems hacky =/

Comment: Well, you technically *can* use a `switch` to check logical expressions as @CataJohn shows in his answer. But, that is some nasty code.

Comment: True but I feel like sticking to if-else for now.. as recommended.. conversion would be nasty

Comment: @ScottMarcus That's right, you actually can and I did not know. Even though it seems kind of hacky =/